# How to check whether a model has a scope defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, scope

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :archived, :checked, :content, :note, :stared

  scope :stared, -> { where(stared: true) 
end
```

With this code, how could I test whether a scope (such as `stared`) is defined on `Idea`. I want to have this effects

```
Idea.has_scope?(:stared) 
=> true
Idea.has_scope?(:unknown)
=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use respond_to?

```
Idea.respond_to?(:stared)
```

Will yield true/false

Comment: It will test against all instance methods other than scopes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method [:valid_scope_name](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/valid_scope_name?) which internally also uses `respond_to?` + is also a protected method + gives a terrible log message. It can be invoked as

```
Idea.send(:valid_scope_name?,:stared)
=> true
```

But this would also mostly, be removed from the edgerails - [git commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f6db31ec16e42ee7713029f7120f0b011d1ddc6c)